# Trackpad Bosto does not working on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, touchpad

I have used Bosto Trackpad for a long period of time on Ubuntu 20.04 and everything worked fine. On Windows it also works well. Can someone help from lsusb I get **ID 05ac:0265 Apple, Inc.**

```
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 006 Device 003: ID 0cf3:311d Qualcomm Atheros Communications Bluetooth
Bus 006 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 003: ID 0000:3825   USB OPTICAL MOUSE
Bus 005 Device 002: ID 05ac:0265 Apple, Inc.
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:0833 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd KU-0833 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

And from  sudo dmesg |grep -i Nuvoton

```
[    4.213781] usb 5-1: Manufacturer: Nuvoton
[    5.357856] input: Nuvoton Mouse as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:05AC:0265.0004/input/input12
[    5.358093] hid-generic 0003:05AC:0265.0004: input,hiddev1,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Nuvoton] on usb-0000:00:13.0-1/input0
[    5.359489] input: Nuvoton Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:05AC:0265.0005/input/input15
[    5.359615] input: Nuvoton Touchscreen as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:05AC:0265.0005/input/input16
[    5.359957] input: Nuvoton as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:05AC:0265.0005/input/input17
[    5.360154] hid-generic 0003:05AC:0265.0005: input,hiddev2,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Device [Nuvoton] on usb-0000:00:13.0-1/input1
[   19.191756] input: Nuvoton as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.0/0003:05AC:0265.0004/input/input20
[   19.192250] magicmouse 0003:05AC:0265.0004: input,hiddev1,hidraw3: USB HID v1.10 Mouse [Nuvoton] on usb-0000:00:13.0-1/input0
[   19.443029] input: Nuvoton as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:13.0/usb5/5-1/5-1:1.1/0003:05AC:0265.0005/input/input21
[   19.443973] magicmouse 0003:05AC:0265.0005: input,hiddev2,hidraw4: USB HID v1.10 Device [Nuvoton] on usb-0000:00:13.0-1/input1
```

Can someone please help? I searched from Internet I cannot understand why it is recognized but not working. Tried to enable in through xinput - did not help.
Thanks for the help in advance)

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! With apologies on behalf of the community, it looks like your question was spammed by a trio of bots that are posting multiple AI-generated answers on questions. Unfortunately, the majority of the Moderators on Stack Exchange sites (including Ask Ubuntu) are on strike *primarily* because the parent company has reduced their ability to remove these bogus answers.  We're hoping that things get back to normal shortly, but in the meantime, we're having to deal with stuff like this. Those answers will be removed ... eventually.